# Strange SQL Criteria Filter Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running an SQL server that runs a lot of queries. But all my queries perform well. But I have this strange query. Here is the query:

```
  SELECT  _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.*
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.SendDate DESC ) AS RowIndex ,
                        ( SELECT    COUNT(SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.PatientID)
                          FROM      SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders
                          WHERE     SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.PatientID <> 0
                                    AND SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.IsReceived = 'True'
                                    AND PatientName LIKE '%%'
                                    AND Category = 'Hematology'
                                    AND ( IsSpacementToDesk = 'true' )
                                    AND ( OrderStatus = 1 )
                                    AND ( IsOrderDone = 'true' )
                                    AND ( ResultApprovedBy IS NULL )
                                    AND OrderTo = 'Laboratory'
                        ) AS NumberOfRows ,
                        SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.*
              FROM      SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders
              WHERE     SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.PatientID <> 0
                        AND SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.IsReceived = 'True'
                        AND PatientName LIKE '%%'
                        AND Category = 'Hematology'
                        AND ( IsSpacementToDesk = 'true' )
                        AND ( OrderStatus = 1 )
                        AND ( IsOrderDone = 'true' )
                        AND ( ResultApprovedBy IS NULL )
                        AND OrderTo = 'Laboratory'
            ) AS _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST
    WHERE   _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex > 0
            AND _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex <= 20
```

If I put 'Chemistry' on the category column filtration it will take 4 second to display the records but if I put 'Hematology' it will take 1 min 30 seconds the number of records found under chemistry is 195 and where as on hematology filteration is 69. I couldn't figure out why the query is slow. Please help

Comment: Off topic: `_PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex > 0` is redundant, it is always true. Please remove superfluous parentheses to help readability. On topic: is this actually a stored procedure? Does it help if you add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: it is not a stored procedure. it is a view. _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex >0 might going to be _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex > 20 and _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex <=40 just to display 20 records per page HoneyBadger

Comment: What is the purpose of `AND PatientName LIKE '%%'`?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan?

Comment: i have checked the execution plan. PatientName Like '%%' is just to try to show any PatientName

Answer (score 2):

< long comment >

Subquery is not linked to the outer query. Do you realize that for every row subquery will return the same value?
`COUNT(SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.PatientID)` - it's a total count of all rows that satisfy filter criteria.

`_PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex <= 20` - `TOP 20 ... ORDER BY` could probably be faster. Because there is no need to number all the rows (no need for `row_number` since you can do `ORDER BY SendDate ASC`).

this code:

```
IsReceived = 'True'
AND IsSpacementToDesk = 'true'
AND OrderStatus = 1
AND IsOrderDone = 'true'
AND ResultApprovedBy IS NULL
```

says that you probably need to redesign your status columns. All these criteria  might mean one particular `status_id`. This could be a computed or persistent column.

Storing booleans as strings is definitely a bad idea. Use `BIT` instead.

To understand what's the problem with performance one should investigate actual execution plan and statistics counters. Although, I doubt a lot that it will show anything except "everything is very bad".

Ad-hoc queries with different filter criteria will be treated by server as two absolutely different queries with probably different execution plans - because string literals are part of the query which make them symbolically different.

Comment: hello, thank you for your detail explanation. the boolean datatypes are actually stored as bit  and i am using string literals only when i am doing criteria area. As for rowindex i am using them for pagination purpose. As for the subquery I want to show my user the number of data they  have found by the search criteria they did on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Your `NumberOfRows` calculation is the same as a `COUNT(*) OVER ()`:

```
SELECT  _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.*
FROM    ( SELECT    Row_Number() Over ( ORDER BY SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.SendDate DESC ) AS RowIndex ,
                    Count(*) Over () AS NumberOfRows ,
                    SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.*
          FROM      SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders
          WHERE     SRH_SearchResultOrientedOrders.PatientID <> 0
                    AND PatientName LIKE '%%'
                    AND Category = 'Hematology'
                    AND ( IsSpacementToDesk = 'true' )
                    AND ( OrderStatus = 1 )
                    AND ( IsOrderDone = 't.rue' )
                    AND ( ResultApprovedBy IS NULL )
                    AND OrderTo = 'Laboratory'
        ) AS _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST
WHERE   _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex > 0
        AND _PATIENT_ORDER_LIST.RowIndex <= 20
```

If it's not improving performance at least it's improving readability